# readInt for scala.io.Source

Tags: scala

In [Console.scala](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/Console.scala.html) we're having nice methods such as `readInt`, `readChar`, etc.

Why don't we have them for `io.Source`? And if you argue we should use Java's IO capabilities, then why having the `Console.read*` methods?

Any other scala-ish method for minimal file parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's worthwhile adding this to the standard library. `Console.readInt` reads a whole line and then converts it to an int. Presumably the use case is when the user is prompted to enter an integer at the console. It's not coded in a defensive way either, try entering a space after the number like `'6 '`

When using `readChar` all the characters in the line are discarded except for the first one.

When using `io.Source` the use case is more about iterating by char or by line. Processing the input with the same semantic as the `Console.read*` method should be rare.

I just saw user unknown's answer and I think it's good.

Comment: What I take from your answer is "indeed, Console.read* is considered harmful, we should remove it, and use `java.util.Scanner` instead". Which I must agree with.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
val sc = new java.util.Scanner (System.in)
```

Comment: Then why `Console.readInt`, when you can `new java.util.Scanner(System.in)`?